Given nonzero $p(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$. Are there infinitely many integers $n$ such that $p(n)\mid n!$ is satisfied?
This problem comes from a famous exercise in elementary number theory:
Prove that there are infinitely many $n\in\mathbb Z_+$ such that $n^2+1\mid n!$.
I know a lot of ways to do this. A fairly easy one is to consider the infinite family of solutions of Pell equations like $n^2+1=5m^2$, then $n\approx\sqrt 5\cdot m>5,m,2m$ for large enough $n$. So $10m^2\mid n!$ in this case.
Now this idea looks hopeless when generalizing the problem to higher degree polynomials $p(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$ instead of $x^2+1$. Because by Thue's theorem these Diophantine equations only have finitely many solutions. So I come up with the following idea:
Consider $n=m^{105}$ so we get $n^2+1=m^{210}+1$. It is "lucky" that
$$m^{210}+1=q_2(m)q_4(m)q_8(m)q_{12}(m)q_{16}(m)q_{24}(m)q_{48}(m)q_{96}(m). $$
Where $q_d(m)$ is a cyclotomic polynomial with degree $d$. Now since $m^{210}+1$ is square free, the $q_d$-s are pairwisely coprime in $\mathbb Q[m]$. So $\mathrm{GCD}(q_{d_1}(m),q_{d_2}(m))$ is bounded for large integers $m$. Since $96<105$, generally $m^{105}!$ has enough factors.
It's relatively easy to see that the idea generalize to $p(x)=x^k+1$. We still could take $n=m^{p_1p_2\cdots p_N}$ where $p_i$-s are different smallest primes. To see this, note that the degree of the $D=2kp_1p_2\cdots p_N$-th cyclotomic polynomial divided by $D$ is no more than $\prod_{i=1}^N(1-p_i^{-1})$. And by an analtic number theoretic fact, $\prod_{i=1}^N(1-p_i^{-1})\to 0$ as $N\to +\infty$. So there must be a large enough $N$ such that the product is less than $1/2k$.
Could we do this trick in the general polynomial $p(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$ case by finding a nice $q(x)$ when $p(q(x))$ have only small enough factors?
Related problem: Prove that there exist infinitely many integers $(n^{2015}+1)\mid n!$

Bober, Fretwell, Martin, and Wooley proved that when $F(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$ is of the form
$$
F(x)=\prod_{j=1}^\ell(a_jx^{k_j}-b_j),\tag1
$$
and $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, there are infinitely many $n$'s for which the largest prime factor of $F(n)$ is $\le n^\varepsilon$. Therefore, we can confirm the result for these types of polynomials:
When $p$ is a prime divisor of $F(n)$ and $\nu_p(\cdot)$ be the $p$-adic valuation, there exists infinitely many $n$ satisfying
$$
\nu_p(n!)\ge\frac np-1\gg n^{1-\varepsilon}\gg\log_pN\gg\nu_p(F(n)).
$$
This means there are infinitely many $n$'s for which $F(n)$ divides $n!$.
NOTE: It is believed in general that all polynomials satisfy the smoothness condition of (1). Little is known for polynomials of degree $\ge2$ that are not in the form of (1), so this is not a complete answer to OP's question.
